# Custom Overload New and Delete Operator

Tags: c++, c++11

```
// Global new and delete operator
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
   cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl;
   void * p = malloc(size); 
   return p;
}
void operator delete(void * p)
{
   cout<< "Overloading delete operator " << endl;
   free(p);
}

class Details
{
    int marks;
    int rollno;
public:
    Details( int marks, int rollno) : marks(marks), rollno(rollno) 
    { 
         cout << "Details Constructor called" << endl;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<< "Marks:" << marks << endl;
        cout<< "rollno:" << rollno << endl;
    }
    ~Details() {  cout << "Details Destructor called" << endl;}
};
class student
{
    string name;
    int age;
    Details* d;
public:
    student()
    {
        cout<< "Constructor is called\n" ;
    }
    student(string name, int age, int marks, int rollno) : name{name},age{age} 
    {
        cout << " Student Constructor called" << endl;
        d = new Details{marks, rollno};
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<< "Name:" << name << endl;
        cout<< "Age:" << age << endl;
        d->display();
    }
    ~student() { cout << " Student Destructor called" << endl; delete d;}   
};
// Driver function
int main()
{
    student * p = new student("Yash", 24 , 5, 1); 
    p->display();
    delete p;
}
```

Output:

```
Overloading new operator with size: 29
Overloading new operator with size: 24
Student Constructor called
Overloading new operator with size: 8
Details Constructor called
Name:Yash
Age:24
Marks:5
rollno:1
Student Destructor called
Details Destructor called
Overloading delete operator 
Overloading delete operator 
Overloading delete operator
```

I expected new and delete opeator functions to be called 2 times (for student and details). But output of the Program shows new and delete operator functions gets called 3 times. Why ?

Comment: I recommend you use a debugger to set breakpoints in your `operator new` and `operator delete` functions, to be able to see the full call-stack which can help you figure out when and where allocations are made.

Comment: Might `std::cout` allocate (at initialization or in writing)?

Comment: Got it ! Its the String.

Comment: `string("Yash")` would also allocate without SSO.

Comment: Note that this implementation of the new operator is problematic on some compilers/compiler options. e.g. GCC does not add a check for null before constructing an object at the memory address you return with the default options, so it could happen that your program is accessing positions at or close to null which results in a SEGFAULT. For this reason you may want to add `if (p == nullptr) throw std::bad_alloc();`

Comment: Furthermore you should change the constructor parameter from `std::string` to `std::string const&` (or possibly even `std::string&&`) to avoid unnecessary allocations. In case of `std::string&&` don't forget to `std::move` to the `name` member variable.

Answer (score 0):

i might be wrong but i think there's another code calling new and delete from one of included libraries